# How to create same runing containers with out --scale in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, test-project

Hy!

I use testproject to ui testing but, when i want to create a docker agent with a compose file, i always recreate my first agent. I renamed it, but it doesn't help. My goal is to create a few same running container to run my test in paralell.
Thanks for help
I used the headless compose file with out job param and job id lines –
hub.docker.com/r/testproject/agent

Comment: What does your `docker-compose.yml` look like?

Comment: Pleas update your original question with the requested resources rather than adding the info in comments. If you remove the `container_name` then you should be able to `—scale` the service using `docker-compose`.

Comment: it doesnt work :/